# How to find the count of the number of documents in mongodb using pymongo aggregation?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, nosql-aggregation

I'm trying to find the max value of a field from a number of documents and want the output to not only reflect the max value of the field but also the total count of documents that the aggregate query will retrieve.

I'm able to retrieve the "wait" field with the max value that I want with the below query, but am stuck with how to get the count of all the documents that are satisfy the below query(Match field).

```
    db = mongo_client[_MONGO_COLLECTION]
    cursor = db.aggregate(
        [
            {"$match": { "owner": { "$exists": False}}},
               {
                "$project": {   
                                "wait" : {
                                                "$divide": [{"$subtract": [datetime.now(), "$creationDate"]}, 1000],

                                            }
                            }
            },                        
               {
                "$sort" : {

                                  "wait": -1
                                                }
                 }, {"$limit" : 1}

    ])
    for x in cursor:
        print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `count` method as below:

```
print(cursor.count())
print(list(cursor))
```

**or**
 you can add `$count` pipeline as below:

```
{
    "$count":"count" // the name of count filed
}
```